# How do I use Vue app in a chrome extension?

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, gulp

I have a vue app that is to be my options page for a chrome extension. I just want to produce the html and js needed to use the vue app, but when I run `npm run build`, `index.html` shows nothing in a browser and I get errors like `GET file:///css/app.8fe112fd.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

My chrome extension is set up using gulp, by the way.

Comment: Are you opening the html file directly from disk? You need to open an extension page using chrome-extension:// URL which happens automatically if you open the options page using the browser UI (like right-clicking the extension icon in the toolbar and clicking "Options") or via chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage()

Comment: Good stuff! Big ups, mate

Comment: I actually created a vue cli plugin to for using Vue.js to develop chrome extension https://github.com/superoo7/vue-cli-plugin-chrome-ext

Comment: thanks a bunch. this actually helped me with my hot-reload problem. i'm not using your package directly but found the command `vue-cli-service build --watch`